# SQL query to retrieve WooCommerce orders grouped by state

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

what I'm trying to retrieve from the Wordpress/WooCommerce database is a list of orders grouped by the states in the US with the Order totals and Order taxes summed for each state.

So the closest I've gotten is this query I've written:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE post_type = "shop_order" 
AND (
meta_key = "_billing_state" 
OR meta_key = "_order_tax" 
OR meta_key = "_order_total"
) 
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

And it returns:

```
meta_key         meta_value
_billing_state   NJ
_order_tax       0.21
_order_total     3.21
_billing_state   NJ
_order_tax       1.75
_order_total     26.70
_billing_state   IA
_order_tax       6.79
_order_total     103.54
_billing_state   PA
_order_tax       1.82
_order_total     27.72
```

...and so on.

What I really need to return is:

```
state  order_tax_sum  order_total_sum
NJ     1.96           29.91
IA     6.79           103.54
PA     1.82           27.72
```

All help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select
    state,
    sum(order_tax_sum),
    sum(order_total_sum)
from (
    select
        (select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm1 where p.ID = pm1.post_id and meta_key = "_billing_state") as state,
        (select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm2 where p.ID = pm2.post_id and meta_key   = "_order_tax") as order_tax_sum,
        (select meta_value from wp_postmeta pm3 where p.ID = pm3.post_id and meta_key   = "_order_total") as order_total_sum
    from
        wp_posts AS p
    WHERE post_type = "shop_order"
) A
group by A.state
```

caveat - totally untested, but the basic idea (do that join in the select statement itself) should be sound

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your exact query and got a 1064 error at line 2 so I'm trying to resolve it.  Any glaring issue on your end?

Comment: you're on mySQL?  I've never used it (sql server and oracle so far), so maybe the brackets aren't allowed?  Unfortunately I don't have a db isntance where I can really test that query.  If that doesn't work, can you post the table structure?  I made some assumptions that may be incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it's on MySQL.  I just removed all of the square brackets and now it's complaining about line 10 "from wp_posts p"

Comment: I added the AS and removed the extra comma at the end of line 9.  Now I'm getting "Unknown column 'p.post_id' in 'where clause'" - I can still post the structure if that will help! Thank you so far!

Comment: doh, that was my bad, it looks like the ID is called post_id in one table but just ID in the other.  I fixed in the above query (as well as the other mistakes I had)

Comment: it may make it easier if you do post it, but hopefully you wont have to :)